# Refreshing a materialized view with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following setup:

## Postgres

In Postgres (Aurora), I've got a materialised view set up. As only the owner of the view is allowed to refresh it, I've created the following function as well to allow other users to refresh it:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refresh_views()
    RETURNS void
    SECURITY DEFINER
AS
$$
BEGIN
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW my_schema.my_view with data;
    RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I go to a SQL terminal and run the following line, the view refreshes as expected:

```sql
SELECT refresh_views();
```

## Python

We use Python with SQLAlchemy/Pandas, and for the most part that works really well. However, I can't seem to get this working properly from Python. Both versions below run without issue and take roughly the same time (~1 minute), but the view is not updated afterwards.

```py
cxn.execute(text("SELECT refresh_views();"))
pd.read_sql(text("SELECT refresh_views();"), cxn)
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call commit at the end of the connection. Command SQL terminal is in `autcommit=True` mode, while a session has default `autocommit=False`.

This post is about your problem: [PostgreSQL materialized view not refreshing from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64019428/postgresql-materialized-view-not-refreshing-from-python)

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I find it strange though as other statements (DDL & UPDATE commands) worked just fine...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I really would like to know how possibly it was a good ideia to have this behavior.